# selenium following element python

Tags: python, html, selenium, checkbox, html-table

I'm using selenium with python.
I have some element that is a checkbox, and I want to click on it.
My problem is with getting that element, I have only the text
In my case `<td>xxxxx</td>` and I want to get the element above it (the previous element, he is not is father, they are only adjacent)
I tried this:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']/following::td[text()='xxxxx']").click()

but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: When you are viewing the elements like in your picture, right click on the element you want and mouse over copy then click on xpath. Just a tip I wish I knew when I started using selenium

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate from td with following xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='xxxxx']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

or  you can try with parent tag and navigate nth td which has input tag like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='xxxxx']/parent::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
```

Comment: It's returning the first column of that row, not the preceding one (the one above it)

Comment: In your html example, i see input tag is present in first td column

Comment: yes, in that case its true. but I tried it on different element, and it was always returning the first column

Comment: I have updated with parent navigation and also update preceding sibiling, that will give immediate sibiling

Comment: unfortunetley it is the same, it's clicking on the first onclick element in the row, and not the one above it

Comment: Do u tried this "//td[text()='xxxxx']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']" ? i m 100% sure this will find immediate preceding sibiling. Please check it in developer console $x("//td[text()='xxxxx']/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']")